# How could I know the update that occurred in foreign column have done because of cascading or by user?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Let me say that I have 3 tables ( _items, _invoiceHeader ,_invoiceDetails)
I built an update trigger on _invoiceDetails , so I can update _balance column in _items table if I update _itemCode. But the problem is if I update the _itemCode column in _items table the trigger on _invoiceDetails table runs immediatly because of cascade rule on _itemCode columns in _items and _invoiceDetails tables.
So how can I know that the update that happened on _invoiceDetails table have done because of cascade or because of the update on the same table _invoiceDetails .

I put this code inside update trigger on _invoiceDetails  table:

```
    if(UPDATE(itemCode)) // I need a condition here to prevent the implementation if the update happened because of cascade rule.
   BEGIN
       UPDATE items
           SET balance=balance+d.quantity
       FROM items
       INNER JOIN DELETED d
       ON items.accountsItemCode=d.accountsItemCode       

       UPDATE items
       SET balance=balance-i.quantity
       FROM items
       INNER JOIN INSERTED i
       ON items.itemCode=i.itemCode
  END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`Trigger_NestLevel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182737%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to determine if your other triggers are active.

Comment: Many thanks . I think you misunderstood me or I didn't write clearly.
So, to be clear. I need a condition to prevent the execution for the update trigger on invoiceDetails table, when it got  released by change the value of primary key(itemCode) in the primary table (items) .
definitely invoiceDetails table has foriegn column which is itemCode. so I don't want to execute  invoiceDetails_trigger when its foreign column(itemCode) changed by the cascade rule in primary table.

Comment: So you're using `ON UPDATE CASCADE` and changing the key value in the `items` table?  Changing the key value is a bit peculiar.  If you disable `ON UPDATE CASCADE` and implement the same functionality in an `UPDATE` trigger on `items` then you can use `Trigger_NestLevel` to determine that another trigger is active.  My preference has been to _never_ have the database cascade on my behalf, but to always implement the functionality I need in stored procedures and, when necessary, triggers.

Comment: Thank you very much .. HABO. I will try to use update trigger instead of UPDATE CASCADE

Answer (score 0):

One of our table design standards is to include meta columns on tables where we want to track changes. We have stuff like UPDATE ID/UPDATE TIMESTAMP or at other times DATA SOURCE.

Generally we pass the corp id of the user calling the procedure and insert that into the table while batch/triggers/any non user action is inserted with some service account name.

Applying such a pattern here would resolve your problem.

Comment: Many thanks . I think you misunderstood me or I didn't write clearly.
So, to be clear. I need a condition to prevent the execution for the update trigger on invoiceDetails table, when it got  released by change the value of primary key(itemCode) in the primary table (items) .
definitely, invoiceDetails table has foriegn column which is itemCode. so I don't want to execute  invoiceDetails_trigger when its foreign column(itemCode) changed by the cascade rule in primary table.

Comment: Ah, now I see. As far as I know there is no automatic way - your best bet would be to check in the trigger if the only value that changed is the FK and maybe check that the old FK no longer exists then skip the remaining logic in your trigger.

Comment: One big warning here is that this sounds like you have ALOT of logic to in the trigger already and you are just adding more - this will impact performance.